# Empty collection parameter in hql query

Tags: java, hql, spring-data

I'm using spring data. 
In my query I'm passing a set as a parameter and using in clause:

```
(pc.currentClubId in (?1))
```

where ?1 is placeholder for the set.
when I'm passing an empty set I get this error:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) and (pc.currentClubId in ())
```

How can i fix this without adding a fake value to the set?

Answer (score 1):

The empty parameter set leads to an invalid sql statement and a runtime-error.
You need to check the size of the parameter set before you execute the query.
If it is empty you can

1. Simple not perform the query if you know that there can't be a non empty result.
2. Dynamically build the HQL string and replace the in-condition with "(1=0)" if the set is empty.
3. Add a value to the parameter set which can't be matched. Obviously this a clumsy solution.